# ModelChoiceField начальный набор списка

Tags: django

Есть форма:

```
class CampaignLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CampaignLocation
        fields = ('location', 'location_type')
        widgets = {
            'location': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control selectpicker',
                    'data-live-search': "true"}
            ),
            'location_type': forms.Select(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            )
        }
```

В списке location огромное количество элементов. Более 80000. Поэтому использую Ajax-Bootstrap-Select для автокомплита. Не знаю как прописать queryset для поля location, чтобы начальное значение было пустым или в списке был только уже выбранный элемент (при изменении)

В моем представлении это должно выглядеть так:

```
class CampaignLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CampaignLocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if ***если location уже задан***:
            self.fields['location'].queryset = ???
        else:
            self.fields['location'].choices = (('', ''),)
```

Что именно я должен проверять и какой должен быть queryset?

Answer (score 1):

У каждого поля формы при инициализации можно передать аргумент 'initial' в котором хранится начальное значение этого поля. При генерации формы из модели каждое поле модели возвращает поле формы с переданным значением в аргументе initial. Аргумент с таким же имененм есть при инициализации самой формы, в него можно передать весь экземпляр модели.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Получается примерно так:

```
class CampaignLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CampaignLocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['location'].initial:
            self.fields['location'].choices = (('%s' % location.pk, location.__unicode__()) for location in self.fields['location'].initial)
        else:
            self.fields['location'].choices = (('', ''),)
```

Comment: Это понятно. Пока прицепил django-autocomplete-light, но для одного - двух полей - не красиво так поступать. Возник вопрос: для уже существующих значений initial по умолчанию передается?

Comment: Да, если используется ModelForm с экземпляром модели, то значения полей обычно подставляются автоматически. Если интересно, посмотрите как работает метод formfield в моделях, вся магия передачи значения происходит там. Если поля у формы прописаны вручную, то обычно значение можно найти в self.initital. Можно вытащить location = self.fields['location'].initial or self.initial.location и потом работать уже с локальной переменной.

Comment: Попробовал. Пока не получается.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CampaignLocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['location'].initial:
            location = self.fields['location'].initial
            self.fields['location'].queryset = self.fields['location'].queryset.filter(location_id=location)
        else:
            self.fields['location'].queryset = self.fields['location'].queryset.none()

Comment: В self.fields['location'].initial что-нибудь передается? А в self.initial?